# Crontab is not working in centos 7

Tags: centos7, cron

I am trying to setup crontab in my centos 7. I have /etc/crontab file is like below.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
*/5 * * * * root /php /root/Downloads/chat/pass.php >/dev/null 2>&1
# For details see man 4 crontabs
```

I want run my pass.php file every 5 minutes. I was able to setup cron in cpanel but I am new in centos 7 and don't know what is wrong in my file or command. I have checked that my cron service is running file. Let me know if there something wrong in it or How can I get log file of cron service.

Thanks

Comment: Is your `php` executable really in the root directory?

Comment: @stickybit Yes, its working fine. I have tested it in terminal like php pass.php

Comment: `php ...` or `/php ...`?

Comment: I am able to run it via only php. like php pass.php

Comment: Then why did you put a slash in the `crontab`?